# use jquery in Django Flatpages

Tags: django, django-flatpages

can use jquery and jquery Ui in Django Flatpages ?
should I host the files locally, or can I specify some external location ??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django Flatpages are much like any normal html page. I suggest you include jQuery and jQuery UI from [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) and host other media (including your jQ UI theme) on your server. Have a look at the [Django docs for handling static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/).